# Running AWS PaaS on my own server

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is it possible to host an EC2 instance on my own own cloud server?  I would like to create an AWS sandbox on my own server, and build a solution using the various AWS services.  Unfortunately I have already squandered my AWS Free Tier.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.
For testing and dev you can use localstack (https://github.com/localstack/localstack)